# How to generate QR to use with Hikvision Camera

Tags: java, camera, qr-code, hikvision

I am creating a simple Java client for the HIKVISION cameras. (Primarily for Linux).

I want to add a feature to let the user generate a QR code base of the camera list (This feature is already exist in Hikevision apps Windows and android).

I read all Hikvision SDK documentation but I could not find anywhere about generating QR Code.

I can generate QR but the question is what data I have to use to generate a QR that is usable by original Hikvision apps as well.

Thanks

Comment: Hey @jaVaBoy did you ever wrk this out? I have the same issue now.

Comment: @Roark , No success, I've just left it ! Didn't find anything to help. I decompiled hik-connect android app. unfortunately, It is an react-native app so couldn't understand how it generate or read QR code.

Comment: Thank you! I took a chance and just created a normal card and turned the card number into a qr code using another library, turns out the hardware the client has does not support QR code reading :D So don't even know if it would've worked! Talk about a waste of time. Cheers!